# relationship between stack ID and stack name in openstack heat

Tags: openstack, orchestration, openstack-heat

I am trying to understand the relationship between stack name and stack ID in openstack heat API http://developer.openstack.org/api-ref-orchestration-v1.html

It seems the stack name is provided by user who want to create the stack by POST while stack ID is generated by heat. But since it is possible to get stack information by 'GET /v1/​{tenant_id}​/stacks/​{stack_name}​/​{stack_id}​', does it imply that a stack name can have multiple stack id? If the answer is positive, what does it mean to have more than one stack IDs applied to the same stack name?

I did not find a clear definition in Heat documentation regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

Correct. Stack name is provided by the user and Stack ID is provided by Orchestration. Stack names are unique. Stack IDs are unique.

A Stack can have only 1 ID.

Fun fact, if you do a

```
GET /v1/​{tenant_id}​/stacks/​{stack_name}​
```

It actually responds with a 302 and redirects you to location

```
GET /v1/​{tenant_id}​/stacks/​{stack_name}​/​{stack_id}​
```

Comment: I honestly don't know. Because it's a snowflake API? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: It's very annoying when the POST and DELETE requests are also redirected.